# linux time result is not written to file

Tags: linux, time, sh

i am using debian. running my program with time command and want the result of time written to a file, doing as follows:

time ./myprog > out.asc

./myprog's output is written to out.asc but not the time's result.
is there any way to send the time's output also to out.asc? thanx!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`time` always writes to stderr.  To save this with bash, use `2>&1` to write to the same place as stdout (you need the parentheses so you get the stderr of time and not just the stderr of myprog):

```
(time ./myprog) > out.asc 2>&1
```

You could also have the timing information go to a separate file:

```
(time ./myprog) > out.asc 2> timing_info
```

Answer (score 1):

(time ./myprog) > out.asc 2>&1

(from http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/26277-redirect-time-output.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try (time ./myprog) >out.asc 2>&1